# ServiceStack MQ: how to populate data in RequestContext

Tags: servicestack, messaging, multi-tenant, requestcontext

I'm developing a JWT-based multi-tenancy system using ServiceStack. The JWT token contains shard information, and I use `JwtAuthProvider` to translate the JWT token to session object following instructions at http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider.

Now, I want to use ServiceStack MQ for asynchronous processing. The MQ request needs to be aware of the shard information, so I populate the request context before executing it as follow

```
mqServer.RegisterHandler<EmployeeAssignedToProject>(m =>
            {
                var req = new BasicRequest { Verb = HttpMethods.Post };
                var sessionKey = SessionFeature.GetSessionKey(m.GetBody().SessionId);
                var session = HostContext.TryResolve<ICacheClient>().Get<Context>(sessionKey);
                req.Items[Keywords.Session] = session;
                var response = ExecuteMessage(m, req);
                return response;
            });
```

Here, `Context` is my custom session class. This technique is stemmed from the instruction at http://docs.servicestack.net/messaging#authenticated-requests-via-mq. Since I execute the message within the context of `req`, I reckon that I should then be able to resolve `Context` as follow

```
container.AddScoped<Context>(c =>
        {
            var webRequest = HostContext.TryGetCurrentRequest();
            if (webRequest != null)
            {
                return webRequest.SessionAs<Context>();
            } else
            {
                return HostContext.RequestContext.Items[Keywords.Session] as Context;                    
            }
        });
```

However, `HostContext.RequestContext.Items` is always empty. So the question is, how to populate `HostContext.RequestContext.Items` from within message handler registration code?

I've tried to dig a little bit into ServiceStack code and found that the `ExecuteMessage(IMessage dto, IRequest req)` in `ServiceController` doesn't seem to populate data in `RequestContext`. For my case, it is a bit too late to get session inside service instance, as a service instance depends on some DB connections whose shard info is kept in session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same Request Context instance can't be resolved from the IOC. The Request Context instance is created in the MQ's `RegisterHandler<T>()` where you can add custom data in the `IRequest.Items` property, e.g:

```
mqServer.RegisterHandler<EmployeeAssignedToProject>(m =>
{
    var req = new BasicRequest { Verb = HttpMethods.Post };
    req.Items[MyKey] = MyValue; //Inject custom per-request data
    //...
    var response = ExecuteMessage(m, req);
    return response;
});
```

This `IRequest` instance is available throughout the Request pipeline and from `base.Request` in your Services. It's not available from your IOC registrations so you will need to pass it in as an argument when calling your dependency, e.g:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public IDependency MyDep { get; set; }

    public object Any(MyRequest request) => MyDep.Method(base.Request, request.Id);
}
```